# A randomly selected policyholder doesn't own an SUV. Find the probability this policyholder owns only one vehicle.

Tags: probability

An auto insurance conducts a study of its policyholders. $30\%$ of the policyholders own an SUV, of which $90\%$ also own another vehicle. Overall, $85\%$ of policyholders own more than one vehicle. A randomly selected policyholder doesn't own an SUV. Find the probability this policyholder owns only one vehicle.

My attempt

---

If I let $P(S) = \text{Probability of SUV and } P(O) = \text{Probability of only one vehicle}$

Then

$P(S) = .3, P(O) = .15, P(O^c)=.85, P(S^c) = .$

$\text{the amount of SUV owners who own more than one vehicle is also }=.3 (.9)$

I don't know how to proceed from here, can anyone give me some hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In other words, it is *given* that the customer doesn't own an SUV.
You are being asked to compute $P(O|S^c)$.

You could approach this in two ways:

1. $P(O|S^c) = \frac{P(O, S^c)}{P(S^c)}$; or
2. $P(O|S^c) = 1-P(O^c|S^c)$.

It will be helpful to remember that $P(A) = P(AB)+P(AB^c)$.

---

I will use 2.

\begin{align*}
P(O|\bar S) &= 1-P(\bar O|\bar S)\\
&=1-\frac{P(\bar O, \bar S)}{P(\bar S)}\\
&=1-\frac{P(\bar O)-P(\bar O, S)}{1-P(S)}
\end{align*}
where the last line is true by the "helpful" line above.
To find $P(\bar O, S)$, condition on $S$.

Comment: I am unsure of how to proceed. I don't see how I have enough information for either of those routes.

Comment: Did you actually try?

Comment: I got $.15$ by doing $P({O\cap S^c\over P(S^c)}) = {(.15)(.27)\over .27}$ but I didn't think it was right

Comment: They're not independent. So you can't just take the product of the probabilities. Try approach 2 and try staring at the "helpful" part for a few minutes.

Comment: I'm not seeing how I compute $P(O\cup B)$

Comment: I updated my answer.